# Arcpy ListDatasets function to specific directories instead of workspace

Tags: arcpy, workspace

Are there any alternatives to the arcpy list functions (ListDatasets, etc.) where the directory can be specified rather than using the env.workspace?

For example, what if I would like to get a list of datasets in several different directories?

Or if I have my workspace in_memory?

The os.walk might partially work, but won't recognize non-file-based data types.  Is another function or snippets that can accomplish this?

Comment: I disagree that the question is duplicate although they share an answer.  If one asked who was the 2nd president of the US, would that be a duplicate to the question of who was the 1st vice president? (John Adams)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that I think may work for you is [**`arcpy.da.Walk()`**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm)

This works in a similar way to `os.walk()` but can walk through geodatabases as well as folders, and recognises spatial data types, tables, feature classes as well as files.

Code sample from the Walk documentation:

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = "c:/data"
feature_classes = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```